# Example REST Extension does not xdmp:log anything when invoking POST

Tags: rest, post, curl, marklogic

I trying to debug a REST extension in MarkLogic by using xdmp:log() inside the XQuery. Seems I am having some issues invoking a POST call in general actually...? Bit confused now.

I use the exact example code as from the MarkLogic documentation [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_63309)

I installed it via Roxy > deploy > ext

It is there when I look into http://host:port/v1/config/resources

The PUT command provided in the doc works and returns the "Done".

But I cannot get the POST statement to dump the xdmp:log messages in the errorlog.txt on the server?

I tried several curl commands:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X POST  http://host:8040/LATEST/resources/example
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Question: What is the correct curl command to trigger the examples POST functon so something shows up in the log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a curl issue. You need to specify a request body for curl to send.

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X POST -d '{"key":"value"}' http://host:8040/LATEST/resources/example
```

Or if you want to send an empty body just do this:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X POST -d '' http://host:8040/LATEST/resources/example
```